# clickhouse array query

Tags: mysql, sql, clickhouse

I have column in a table with data type `Array(Int32)`.To query a item in array, I am using the below query.

```
select count(id) from user where has(array,2);
```

How to query multiple elements in the array? is there any `in` query in clickhouse?

I want query like mentioned below

```
select count(id) from user where has(array,2) or has(array,3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hasAll](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/array-functions/#hasall) function Checks whether one array is a subset of another.

Answer (score 0):

I never used clickhouse but I think there is an workaround to check if an array contains all the entries given.

```
select count(id) 
from user 
where arrayUniq(arrayConcat(array, [2, 3])) = arrayUniq(array)
```

If you want to check if one or many entries are there I think would be like:

```
select count(id) 
from user 
where arrayUniq(arrayConcat(array, [2, 3])) < length(arrayConcat(array, [2, 3]))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think second query should be `<=`.

Comment: arrayUniq returns length, no need of calling length function again

Comment: If equals then it means that array doesn't contain any of the searched values which we don't want

Comment: Thta solution is far from optimal. Use `hasAny` function as Ivan Blinkov propose.

Comment: for sure.. couldn't find those functions in the documentation.. If they exists then they must be used rather then my proposals